# Weird problem with Android/Java method. Control seems to jump across if/else block

Tags: java, android, recursion

In the following Android sample, I have a set of JSON objects(referred to as templates) and I'm doing a sort of inheritance processing on them. If a JSON object has a key "extends", the corresponding value will refer to another JSON object. I just copy the mappings in the referred JSON object to the current one. Each property (referred to as component in the code) will have sub properties, so each sub property is copied individually.
All the JSON objects are stored in a HashMap.
EDIT: Posting sample code which demonstrates the issue.

```
package com.trial;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Trial extends Activity {

    HashMap<String, JSONObject> templates = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        try {
            templates.put("entity", new JSONObject("{\"Health\":{\"health\":50,\"maxHealth\":100}}"));
            templates.put("unit", new JSONObject("{\"Health\":{\"health\":70},\"extends\":\"entity\"}"));
            Iterator<String> templatesIterator = templates.keySet().iterator();
            while (templatesIterator.hasNext()) {
                String templateName = templatesIterator.next();
                JSONObject template = templates.get(templateName); 
                if (template.has("extends"))
                    templates.put(templateName, processInheritance(template));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private JSONObject processInheritance(JSONObject template) throws JSONException {
        if (template.has("extends")) {
            //If current template extends from another template
            String parentTemplateName = template.getString("extends");
            template.remove("extends");
            JSONObject parentTemplate = processInheritance(templates.get(parentTemplateName));
            //Create a clone of the parent to which child properties/components can be added
            JSONObject processedTemplate = new JSONObject(parentTemplate.toString());
            Iterator<String> it = template.keys();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String componentName = it.next();
                if (processedTemplate.has(componentName)) {
                    //Component is already present. Loop through Component properties and make
                    //specific replacements
                    JSONObject componentData = template.getJSONObject(componentName);
                    Iterator<String> it2 = componentData.keys();
                    JSONObject processedComponentData = processedTemplate.getJSONObject(componentName); 
                    while (it2.hasNext()) {
                        String propertyName = it2.next();
                        processedComponentData.put(propertyName, componentData.get(propertyName));
                    }
                    processedTemplate.put(componentName, processedComponentData);
                } else {
                    //Component is not already present. Simply copy
                    processedTemplate.put(componentName, template.get(componentName));
                }
            }
            return processedTemplate;
        } else {
            return template;
        }
    }
}
```

On debugging I noticed that the code executes fine until after the while loop. Soon after the while loop, it jumps across the if/else and returns "template" instead of "processedTemplate". Even the resulting object indicates that "template" is being returned. I've tried clearing the binaries, recreating the emulator, and executing it on the actual device. The weird behavior persists. Could you someone tell me why this happens?

EDIT: The correct object IS being returned. My earlier comment that "template" was being returned was because of a bug where I was not saving the returned process object back into the HashMap. 
I was simply doing

```
if (template.has("extends"))
    processInheritance(template));
```

However the control still seems to jump across. An problem with Eclipse, I suppose.

Comment: Is your debugging information compiled correctly and can you be sure Eclipse hasn't lost sync with the relevant line numbers? This happens occasionally to me - Eclipse shows line X in the debugger which is wrong because the source is on line Y etc - and a Project->Clean helps.

Comment: I agree with atc, sometimes the debugger seems to lose line numbers' right references. A classic Clean or even closing eclipse is sometimes enough.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I've cleaned eclipse, re created the emulator, restarted my machine and even tried it out on an actual device.

Comment: Not sure I trust this observation... :)  Try moving the "return template" to the end of the function (outside the try block) ... it'll make the code easier to read if nothing else.

Comment: which `while` is jumped over? the inner or the outer one?

Comment: sorry, I meant "after which `while` is the `if` jumped over? the inner or the outer one?" (I see no if to be jumped over after any while!)

Comment: To see what's going on, I'd try swapping the order of the if/then so you're calling if (!template.has("extends")) { return template } else {... your stuff ...}.

Comment: Can you also post a sample of your JSON data so we can step through this?  Also, +1 for using recursion!

Comment: @jmort253: I'd award -1 for using recursion! It's easy to get confused when debugging recursive code. Say you have a breakpoint in your function and you absent-mindedly try to step over a recursive call... the fact you're suddenly in a new stack frame for the breakpoint you just hit can be far from obvious. IIRC it can look like your instruction pointer just jumped randomly, which is why I don't trust the original observation.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but rather than cloning the JSONObject which was returned, which repeatedly clones it at every extension level as more detail is added, should you not clone the template returned in the else so that the cloning only happens at the root of the extension hierarchy (that is the first template object which does not itself extend something else)?

Comment: Swapping the if/then fixed the problem, but the control still jumps around when using the above code.

Comment: @Pedro Loureiro: Jumps across the outer if/else. The code executes until the return statment, and then moves over to the other return (in the else block).

Comment: @Reuben Scratton: I assumed that in the beginning too. I've set the breakpoint before the function gets called, so it can't be an issue of getting confused about which "instance" of the function is currently executing.

Comment: @Evans I still don't trust the observation I'm afraid... as jmort253 said, any chance you can post some JSON so we can help investigate? FWIW I step through Java code in Eclipse a lot and also see the current instruction going to funny places sometimes. I guess that's down to compiler optimizations. Are you absolutely certain the return value is from the impossible code path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code as below seems to have fixed the issue, but the problem with the original code snippet still remains.

```
private JSONObject processInheritance(JSONObject template) throws AssetLoadingException {
        try {
            if (!template.has("extends")) {
                return template;
            } else {
                //Everything else
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            throw new AssetLoadingException(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to debug your code using Eclipse and it seems to work if I understand it's goal correctly. The debugger seems to behave as you described: when it should return `processedTemplate`, it skips to the line with `template`. However, `processedTemplate` is returned, as expected. The debugger seems to jump out of a function always from the last `return` statement.

I would say that the problem is not in this code. Maybe you should post some JSON example files with which the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because it's a recursive method and you are effectively removing a key and then iterating over the list of remaining keys, that this gets messed up somehow during recursion. Try not removing the "extends" key but rather ignore it when iterating through the key set.

Comment: I don't see how that makes the debugger jump across control blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual machine would never have this kind of an error, so there is a good chance your recursive approach as a bug.
I can't pinpoint it right away, but a couple System.out.println(template); might help.

Comment: I guess it's a problem with the debugger. I'm not able to post the code as is, I'll try to post an example data set.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you will processInheritance of all objects, until you get the root one. (The one that doesn't have an "extends" value.)

Hence, the first return that you find is the one in the `else` branch.

Repeating my explanation:

Here is your striped-down code:

```
private JSONObject processInheritance(JSONObject template) throws AssetLoadingException {
        try {
            if (template.has("extends")) {

                JSONObject parentTemplate = processInheritance(templates.get(parentTemplateName));

                }
                return processedTemplate;
            } else {
                return template;
            }
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            throw new AssetLoadingException(ex);
        }
    }
```

If you've got the sequence `ROOT <- C <- B <- A` (where B extends A and so-on) and start evaluating A, this is what will happen:

1. process A
2. A is extending B (`has "extends")`, so process B
3. B is extending C, so process C
4. C is extending ROOT, so process ROOT
5. ROOT extends nothing so enter the `else` and return template.

(then there will be a sequence of returns after finishing processing C, B and A)